# Books on history of biochemistry

Tags: chemistry, biology, book-recommendation, biochemistry

I am looking for books on the history of biochemistry. Searching online there are some short articles that can be found, which just mention a few highlights, but I haven't really found more comprehensive works.

I am hoping for books that explain the history of biochemistry, with the aim of understanding how we have reached our current knowledge of the different biomolecules and their structure and biological function, and different biochemical pathways.

Thank you.

Comment: Google "history of biochemistry" and select "books" from the bar at the top of the search page (in drop-down menu under [⋮More] button). There are [many hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=history+of+biochemistry&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF1OL6hPPyAhXhKVkFHYqvAmkQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1252&bih=548).

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for the comment. There are maybe a few results there that seem okay. Many of the hits there are duplicates and considering unique results many of them are not really about biochemistry in general, e.g. there's one about "personal recollections", and one specifically about the University of Melbourne, etc. There are 1-2 there which would potentially match what asked AFAIS, e.g. "Vital Forces". I'd still leave this question open for recommendations if that's fine, in case there are some other ones I missed, especially if someone can recommend from personal experience